# How to statistic the historical data using R language?

Tags: r

I have a data.frame named A as the following:

```
uid    uname     csttime                   action_type
1      felix     2014-01-01 01:00:00         1
1      felix     2014-01-01 02:00:00         2
1      felix     2014-01-01 03:00:00         2
1      felix     2014-01-01 04:00:00         2
1      felix     2014-01-01 05:00:00         3
2      john      2014-02-01 01:00:00         1
2      john      2014-02-01 02:00:00         1
2      john      2014-02-01 03:00:00         1
2      john      2014-02-02 08:00:00         3
.......
```

I want to statistic the historical action_type for each `<uid,uname,csttime>` combination, for example, for `<1,'felix','2014-01-01 03:00:00'>`, I want to know how many different `action_types` have ever occurred. Here, for `<1,'felix','2014-01-01 03:00:00'>`, the `action_type_1` is 1 and the `action_type_2` is 1.

Comment: Do you mean the result for action_type_2 for felix is 3?  Please show how you want the results to look.

Comment: Yeath. the action_type_2 for <1,felix,'2014-01-01 05:00:00'> is 3 and for <1,felix,'2014-01-01 04:00:00'> is 2. That is, I want to add a action_type_1 and action_type_2 for each row and the value of action_type_1 is the number of action_type that equal to 1 occured, the action_type_2 is the number of action_type that equal to 2 occured.

Comment: Please edit your question to reflect that. And add a display of how you want the results structured.

Answer (score 3):

If I'm understanding your question correctly I believe there is a fairly simple dplyr answer.

```
library(dplyr)

group_by(stack, uid, uname, csttime) %>%
count(uid, action_type)
```

This will yield:

```
  uid action_type n
1   1           1 1
2   1           2 3
3   1           3 1
4   2           1 3
5   2           3 1
```

as you can see this gives you each unique id, the action types they have taken and the number of times.  if you want to say, change to include date, you can do

```
group_by(stack, uid, uname, csttime) %>%
    count(uid, csttime, action_type)
```

hope that helps.